# Php code that will output the value(can be number or literals) of sql

Tags: php, sql

I have this:

```
$query = "SELECT time  FROM table_schedule GROUP BY time ORDER BY count(*) desc LIMIT 1 ";
```

then I stored it in:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I will output the value by `<?php echo $result ?>` but I am always getting this value `Resource id #20.`

I am new in sql so I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show the result in a unproper way. In PHP `mysql_query()` will execute a query. In order to get the result, you should use

```
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);   // fetches the result of the query and stores in an associative array
$time=$row['time'];    // get the result from the associate array with field name as the index
```

You can also use ,

```
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result); 
$time=$row[1];
```

which will fetch the result as an enumerated array where you want to display each fields with the column number starting from 0.

[For reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Comment: ^ it should be you not I. haha. sorry